# JQuery: removing option from select by data-attribute LESS than

Tags: jquery, html

I need to ask you for a help.
I have following select:

```
<select id="some_id">
    <option value="1" data-cost_level="1">option A</option>
    <option value="4" data-cost_level="2">option B</option>
    <option value="9" data-cost_level="3">option C</option>
</select>
```

And now I need to remove (using JQuery) all the options with data-cost_level LESS THAN 3.
Is it possible with one-line-instruction without looping through entire select?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "one-line" - jquery.min.js is "one-line".  Also, "without looping" - what do you think `$("select>option")` is going to do... it's going to loop... so again, depends on your definition of "loop".  The simplest would be a `.filter(function)` - but that's "looping".

Comment: I think filter could be a very good idea but I tried something like this:
$("#some_id").filter(function(){
                   return $(this).attr('data-cost_level') < "3"
                }).remove();
but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get all nodes matching **option[data-cost_level]** and if attribute "value" is less than 3, remove them with $('selector').remove()

```js
document.querySelectorAll('option[data-cost_level]').forEach((item)=>{
  if($(item).attr('value')<3){
     $(item).remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="some_id">
            <option value="1" data-cost_level="1">option A</option>
            <option value="4" data-cost_level="2">option B</option>
            <option value="9" data-cost_level="3">option C</option>
</select>
```

Comment: FYI: worth a read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt:

```
// split to 3 lines from 1 so it's easier to see here
$("#some_id").filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).attr('data-cost_level') < "3" }
).remove();
```

is close.

First, you need to `.filter` the `option`s not the `select`, so change to

```
$("#some_id > option")
```

next, if you compare strings, you won't get numeric comparison, so `("21"<"3")===true` so you need to convert to int, there's various ways to do this, the easiest is to use `.data()` instead of `.attr()` which, in jquery, will auto-convert to the correct data type (then compare with an int), ie:

```
$(this).data("cost_level") < 3
```

including a test-harness, this gives:

```js
$("#btn").click(() => {
  var val = $("#inp").val() * 1;

  $("#some_id > option").filter(function() {
    return $(this).data("cost_level") < val;
  }).remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="some_id">
  <option value="1" data-cost_level="1">option A</option>
  <option value="4" data-cost_level="2">option B</option>
  <option value="9" data-cost_level="3">option C</option>
</select>
<hr/>
<input id='inp' value='3'><button type='button' id='btn'>clear</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a working solution with explanation.